# how to get a <td> value after clicking the row

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to get the third column in a selected row. my jquery is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(function() {
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: false
            });
            $(".tweetButton").on("click", function() {
                $("#dialog").dialog("open");
            });
        });

        $("#submit").click(function() {
            var MyRows = $('table#ForChangingTweet').find('tr').click(function() {
            });
            var MyIndexValue = "hai";
            for (var i = 0; i < MyRows.length; i++) {
                MyIndexValue = $(MyRows[i]).find('td:eq(2)').html();

            }
            alert(MyIndexValue);
        });
    });

while my table is 

    <table cellspacing="20" class ="tweetTable" id="ForChangingTweet" >
        <caption>Tweets</caption>
        <% while(rs.next()){ %>
        <tr >
            <td><%=rs.getString(1)%></td>
            <td><%=rs.getString(2)%></td>
            <td><%=rs.getString(3)%></td>
            <td><input type="button" class="tweetButton" value="Edit Tweet" /></td>
        </tr>
        <% } %>
    </table>
```

My program is working fine but the loop in the jqery is iterating through all value under third column but i want third column value on which i will click the button. In the table every row has a button as i have given the code. When o will click the button then it should give the third of that row and it should alert through alert(MyIndexValue); Can someone tell that how i can get.

```
<div id="dialog">
    <form method="post">
        <label>New Tweet:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name"><br/>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /><input type="submit" value="Delete" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Above is my dialog box which will open when i will click the 'Edit Tweet' button
Can someone help me to get the answer of this question i got stuck in this. and not getting any solution.

Comment: check step by step tutorial on how to get table cell TD value http://codepedia.info/jquery-get-table-cell-td-value-div/

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
        $(".tweetButton").on("click", function() {
            $('.tweetButton').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        });

        now use for $('.tweetButton.selected').parent().prev().text() in the submit button
```